# How to implement register blocking for 3D finite-difference stencil computations

Tags: finite-difference, hpc, 3d

I am in need to optimize the performance of the 3D solver that integrates a system of equations for seismic wave propagation.
Unsurprisingly, the function that implements the finite-difference stencil computations, is the bottleneck of the computations.

I read [this article](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.407.3398&rep=rep1&type=pdf), where in Section 3.2 the authors say that the register blocking allowed them to obtain substantial speedup of the 3D stencil computations.

I do not understand how to implement this technique.
Is it possible to find somewhere the description of register blocking in clear form?

Comment: Is it any different from regular blocking, except instead of fitting a block into cache, you fit it into some SSE registers?

Comment: This is what I try to understand.